# Python: Probit Regression with interaction term of two categorial variables

Tags: python, regression, data-analysis, statsmodels, interaction

I want to run a probit regression (see model below) in which two dummy variables (gender x treatment) interact. However, when including treatment*gender in the model, I get the error message "categorical data cannot be >1-dimensional".
Compared to using other analysis software I get approximate results through creating an additional dummy which takes the value 1 if both dummies equal 1 - but I don't think this is quite correct with respect to the underlying statistical model. The marginal effect of the interaction would have to be the cross-derivative of treatment*gender and not simply the derivative by co-occurrence.
Unfortunately, I can't find anything about this in the Stats models documentation. How do I correctly include the interaction term?

Thank you very much!

```
probit_model = probit("decision ~ gender + treatment1 + treatment2 + 
              control1 + control2 + contorl3 + treatment1*Gender + treatment2*Gender", data_probit).fit() 
              #here the error raises

probit_model = probit("decision ~ gender + treatment1 + treatment2 + 
               treatment1_Gender + treatment2_gender + control1 + control2 + contorl3", data_probit).fit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
probit_model = probit("decision ~ control1 + control2 + contorl3 + 
                      treatment1*Gender + treatment2*Gender",
                      data_probit).fit()
```

Looking at `patsy`'s documentation [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/example_formulas.html), it looks like patsy automatically adds the main effects when using `*`. That means by specifying `treatment1*gender`, it is interpreted as `treatment1+gender+treatment1:gender` automatically. The first two terms here are repeated from your formula.

If this does not work, please provide a minimal reproducible example including data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Great. If this helped, please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the `v` sign next to the beginning on the left. @rosa.